# How to search trends using tweepy?

Tags: python, tweepy

I'm coding a bot, and I need to search up the trends that I record. But tthe search result that returns is just [], aka, nothing. Here's a pastebin of the code. https://pastebin.com/pkJ2McUq  And a code snippet.

```
import tweepy
APIKey=input("API Key, Please.\n")
APIKeysecret=input("And To Confirm, Your Secret Api Key.\n")
AccessToken=input("Your Access Token?\n")
AccessTokenSecret=input("And The Secret Token.\n")
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(APIKey, APIKeysecret)
auth.set_access_token(AccessToken, AccessTokenSecret)
with open("TrendsResult/atrendsresults.json", 'w') as atrendssearchresults :
   print(api.search('IndividualTrends/0.txt', lang="EN", result_type = "popular"), file=atrendssearchresults)
 with open("TrendsResult/btrendsresults.json", 'w') as btrendssearchresults :
   print(api.search('IndividualTrends/1.txt', lang="EN", result_type = "popular"), file=btrendssearchresults)
 with open("TrendsResult/ctrendsresults.json", 'w') as ctrendssearchresults :
   print(api.search('IndividualTrends/2.txt', lang="EN", result_type = "popular"), file=ctrendssearchresults)  
 with open("TrendsResult/dtrendsresults.json", 'w') as dtrendssearchresults :
   print(api.search('IndividualTrends/3.txt', lang="EN", result_type = "popular"), file=dtrendssearchresults)  
 with open("TrendsResult/etrendsresults.json", 'w') as etrendssearchresults :
   print(api.search('IndividualTrends/4.txt', lang="EN", result_type = "popular"), file=etrendssearchresults)  
 with open("TrendsResult/ftrendsresults.json", 'w') as ftrendssearchresults :
   print(api.search('IndividualTrends/5.txt', lang="EN", result_type = "popular"), file=ftrendssearchresults)  
 with open("TrendsResult/gtrendsresults.json", 'w') as gtrendssearchresults :
   print(api.search('IndividualTrends/6.txt', lang="EN", result_type = "popular"), file=gtrendssearchresults)
 with open("TrendsResult/htrendsresults.json", 'w') as htrendssearchresults :
   print(api.search('IndividualTrends/7.txt', lang="EN", result_type = "popular"), file=htrendssearchresults)    
 with open("TrendsResult/itrendsresults.json", 'w') as itrendssearchresults :
   print(api.search('IndividualTrends/8.txt', lang="EN", result_type = "popular"), file=itrendssearchresults)
 with open("TrendsResult/jtrendsresults.json", 'w') as jtrendssearchresults :
   print(api.search('IndividualTrends/j.txt', lang="EN", result_type = "popular"), file=jtrendssearchresults)
```

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of those searches will return any results because there are no Tweets that match those queries.
The first parameter for [`API.search`](https://tweepy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#API.search) is the search query string, and you're searching for the strings themselves instead of whatever is in the files that they reference.
Also, you should look into using loops.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys
import tweepy
import json

#Autenticações
consumer_key = ''
consumer_secret = ''
access_token = ''
access_token_secret = ''

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

# Where On Earth ID for Brazil is 23424768.
BRAZIL_WOE_ID = 23424768

brazil_trends = api.trends_place(BRAZIL_WOE_ID)

trends = json.loads(json.dumps(brazil_trends, indent=1))

for trend in trends[0]["trends"]:
    print (trend["name"]).strip("#")
```

More explanation can be found here:[Click here](https://ronanlopes.me/tweepy-retrieving-trending-topics-twitter-specific-location/)